# Power BI - Rankx and filter

Tags: powerbi

I have got below table and want to add calculated column **Rank (oldest top-3)** that ranks only when Status is "O". Note that **Rank (oldest top-3)**is the desired result.

```
Status  Days open   Rank (oldest top-3)
C       1   
O       1           4
O       2           3
C       3   
C       4   
C       5   
O       6           2
O       7           1
C       8   
C       9
```

I have got below code but they do not work for me.

```
Rank = IF(order[Status] = "C", BLANK(),
          RANKX(FILTER(order, order[Status] = "O"),
                order[Days open], , 1, Dense))
```

I get top 3 and not the botom one. Also, with filter it filter out any other data. I tried to replace FILTER with ALLSELECTED but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

## Input

I have created a table named `order` with the following data:

```
Status  Days open
C       1
O       1
O       2
C       3
C       4
C       5
O       6
O       7
C       8
C       9
```

## Code

Then I have added a calculated column with the following DAX:

```
Rank = 
IF('order'[Status] = "C", 
    BLANK(),
    RANKX(
        FILTER('order', 'order'[Status] = "O"),
        'order'[Days open], 
        , 
        0, 
        Dense
        )
)
```

The only difference compared to your DAX (apart from formatting) is that the second to last option of the `RANKX` function is `0` instead of `1`.
The [documentation of `RANKX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/rankx-function-dax) indicates that `0` ranks the series in descending order.

## Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`FILTER('order', 'order'[Status] = "O")`,change to `FILTER(all('order'), 'order'[Status] = "O")`,if not, your resutls may the all the same in one table.